# Firebase: collectionGroup.doc is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database is shaped like this:

```
 - Song [Collection]
    - Some
    - Data

- User [Collection]
    - Some
    - Data
    - likedSong [Collection]
      - Same 
      - Data as
      - Songs
```

So the users can like some songs and they are stored in the user document.

But when a song is removed, I want that also the record under user is deleted.

How can I achieve this?

My first thought was this:

```
firestore.collectionGroup("likedSongs").doc(song.id).delete();
```

but I get this error

```
firestore.collectionGroup(...).doc is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[collectionGroup()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Firestore#collectiongroup) returns a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) object, which you can see from the linked API documentation, does not have a method called `doc()`.  If you want to see if that collection group has a document with a specific ID, you will have to store the document ID as a field in the document, and use that as a filter in the query.  After that, you would have to handle the results of the query normally by iterating the results.

```
firestore
    .collectionGroup("likedSongs")
    .where("id", "==", song.id)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        for (const doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
            doc.ref.delete();
        }
    })
```